# Find highest value in a list with For loop

Tags: python, for-loop, max

I have a list of scores, and I'd like to find the highest values in the list (in my example below, it is the value 80).

```
scores = [60,29,60,43,10,9,80,45,23,80,56,4]

highest_score = 0

for i in scores:
    
    if i >= highest_score:
        highest_score = i
        print (highest_score, scores.index(highest_score) )
```

For `highest_scores`, it returns `[60,60,80,80]`, whereas I'd like to get only the highest value `80`.
For `scores.index(highest_score)`, it is giving me the indexes `[0,0,6,6]`, whereas I'd like to get the indexes of the highest value - that should be `[6,6]`.

How can I improve my code to get the desired outcome?

Comment: dont print inside the for-loop

Comment: Yes, I've tried that. It prints only one value 80, which solves the problem with highest_score. But I can't get the two indexes of the value 80

Comment: store the indices also as a variable.  "highest_score_index"

Comment: Not sure, it makes a difference to store them, since it will give the same output anyway - which is [0,0,6,6]

Comment: when you find a new high score you start a new array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for the indexes of the highest values in `[60,29,60,43,10,9,80,45,23,80,56,4]`, I think you mean you want: `[6, 9]`.

Assuming that you want a "native" implementation of the algorithm without having to resort to the `max()` function, and that you want the indexes I recommend you use `enumerate(scores)`:

```
scores = [60,29,60,43,10,9,80,45,23,80,56,4]

highest_score = scores[0]
indexes = []

for i, s in enumerate(scores):
  if s > highest_score:
    indexes = []
  if s >= highest_score:
    indexes.append(i)
    highest_score = s

print(highest_score, indexes)
```

Result:

```
80 [6, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find max value by:

```
max(scores)
```

Returns `80`.

Comment: I know, but my exercise consists on finding the value with a loop and without an in-built function.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake you are doing is in the indentation for print statement. It should be outside the loop. Try the below code:

```
scores = [60, 29, 60, 43, 10, 9, 80, 45, 23, 80, 56, 4]

highest_score = 0

for i in scores:
    if i >= highest_score:
        highest_score = I

# find all indices of the highest_score
indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(scores) if x == highest_score]
print(highest_score, indices)
```

I have also written a list comprehension for finding all the indices of the highest score in the list, as your code would only return the index of the first occurrence.

Output:

```
80 [6, 9]
```

Comment: It's a great solution, thanks! Is there another way that would about a second for loop for the indexes?

Comment: I think you got the desired solution from MarinaMogilko69.

Answer (score 1):

There are better ways to do it, however since you want to do it using for loops, this should work:

```
scores = [60,29,60,43,10,9,80,45,23,80,56,4]

highest_score = 0
index_list = []

for i in scores:   
   if i >= highest_score:
       highest_score = i

for i in scores:
   if i == highest_score:
       index_list.append(scores.index(i))

print (highest_score , index_list )
```

Output:

```
>>> 80 [6, 6]
```

Comment: Is there a way to do everything in one for loop?

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
scores = [60,29,60,43,10,9,80,45,23,80,56,4]

highest_score = 0
highest_score_index=[]

for index, score in enumerate(scores):
    if score > highest_score:
        highest_score = score
        highest_score_index.clear()
        highest_score_index.append(index)
    elif score == highest_score:
        highest_score_index.append(index)
        
print (highest_score, highest_score_index )
```

for single for loop.

Returns:
`80 [6, 9]`

Answer (score 0):

```
scores = [60,29,60,43,10,9,80,45,23,80,56,4]
highest_score = None
highest_score_indexes = []

for index, value in enumerate(scores):
    if index == 0:
        highest_score = value
        highest_score_indexes.append(index)
    else:
        if highest_score > value:
            pass
        elif highest_score == value:
            highest_score_indexes.append(index)
        elif highest_score < value:
            highest_score = value
            highest_score_indexes = [index]

print("heighest score {}".format(highest_score))
print("heighest score indexes {}".format(highest_score_indexes`enter code here`))
```